# How do I contribute to an npm package?

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I am using *gulp-jade* package in my project. It is added as a dev-dependency so I can run **npm install** to fetch it easily(together with others). Now, I need to do some performance optimization in *jade* module, which is a dependency of *gulp-jade*.

So far I can think of the following way:

1. fork both *jade* and *gulp-jade*,
2. change forked *gulp-jade* to use forked *jade*
3. update my package.json to use forked *gulp-jade*
4. make a pull request for *jade*
5. when/if pull request is accepted, switch back to *gulp-jade* from npm

It does not seem very simple though, especially because I might need to make changes not only in *jade* itself, but also in its dependencies, therefore, I would have to fork them also.

That's lots of forking!

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Though if you want your changes/optimisations to be incorporated into the `master` branch of a module, you have no other way but to send a pull request to the maintainer or fork and maintain the module yourself with your code changes but here is a workflow I suggest that may reduce a bit of effort on your side.

Fork only the top level module you wish to make changes to which in this case is the `gulp-jade` module. Use your forked `gulp-jade` in your project. If you wish to make changes to it's dependencies, do so in a separate branch(per dependency) and then merge it into the main module branch which is again, the `gulp-jade` module.

Adopt a branch naming convention that helps you identify easily which module was changed in that branch and which dependency tree it affects. At the end, you will have a branch tree with each module's changes sitting in it's own branch nicely.

From here on, simply fork the corresponding module, add the remote, upstream the module branch and then send a pull request to the maintainer.

Once all your pull requests are accepted, you can switch the local `gulp-jade` module with the remote one.