# How do I contribute to npm development

Tags: node.js, npm, open-source

I want to contribute to the npm project in github. Particularly I am trying to pick the Issues and solve them.

However, I could not locate resources which guide in setting up development environment for npm in Windows OS.

I already understand in github I have to fork from npm project and then request a pull once the changes are done. I am searching for answers for the following -

1. What should I do to test the changes I make to the npm locally in a Windows environment?

[[Edit]]

e.g. If I edit the file (only hypothetically) https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/lib/access.js locally to fix an issue, what should I do to test my changes locally? Should I run a compile, or should I simply invoke npm command? What should I do?

I came across similar question in SO - [How do I contribute to an npm package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000866/how-do-i-contribute-to-an-npm-package), but this is about a package.

I want to understand the development process flow for npm itself.

Please note I have a Windows environment where I want to set up the dev chain for npm.

Comment: isn't it an off-topic?

Comment: Hw is it off topic? I did not understand!

Comment: Read the Question Policy of stackoverflow. Is your question about programming?

Comment: Can you please quote the statement in question policy which you feel violates? I could not spot the one which is violating the policy. My question is towards contributing to an open source project - npm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all the information you need on the [npm github wiki](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki).  This includes contributing guidelines, the code review process, and so on.

Beyond that, your question is really too broad.  You're asking very general questions rather than a single specific question that can be answered.

Also, arguably, you're asking for help that is found in an off-site resource.  Often, large open source projects will have rules for contributing.  If not, there are [many](https://blog.newrelic.com/2014/05/05/open-source_gettingstarted/) [good](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-participate-or-contribute-in-open-source-projects) resources about how to contribute to open source.

Comment: thank you for guiding. I browsed the wiki but could not understand it. But I have to work on it. I thank you more on highlighting on the reason this question is not so good. Trust me it helped me a lot in the thought process. Thank you once again!